# AWS CLI and SAM CLI are not found on Jenkins Pipeline script (Jenkins run as Docker instance)

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, aws-cli

I have a script as

```
pipeline {

    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                git branch: "master", credentialsId: "ritefit.io", url: "git@bitbucket.org:ritefitio/my-project.git"
            }
        }

        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo $PATH'
                sh 'aws s3 ls'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I got the below one as the output

```
> /var/jenkins_home/workspace/question-app-pipeline@tmp/durable-af9dc286/script.sh:
> 1:
> /var/jenkins_home/workspace/question-app-pipeline@tmp/durable-af9dc286/script.sh:
> aws: not found
```

If I ssh to the instance to run aws s3, it is working as normal. But not from Jenkins pipeline.
I also tried to echo $PATH and I do see the 'aws' path is already included.

The same is happening for sam cli.

Please help me out please. It has been couple days which I search and apply many ways but no luck so far

**Note: Jenkins run under Docker instance** 
**I think that is the issue. I have logged inside the docker and I got the same issue.**

Comment: Can you post the output of `$PATH` here? Also, did you try using the full path of aws like `/usr/bin/aws` instead of `aws` simply?

Comment: Output of the $PATH is /usr/local/openjdk-8/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: /usr/bin/aws s3 is working fine with the Jenkins box, but not working via Jenkins pipeline script

Comment: try running `which aws` in your pipeline and post the output here.

Comment: it is /usr/bin/aws

Comment: Does any of the agents in your Jenkins config has aws cli installed?

Answer (score -1):

did you try to run aws command as jenkins user in the agent or instance ?  or try "sudo aws s3 ls"

Comment: 'sudo aws s3 ls' is working fine if I run directly on the instance which I ssh to